# SQL Stored Procedure Parameters being Corrupted?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that for now is just suppose to validate your string input as a valid date. I've tried running this outside of a procedure and it works flawlessly, but as soon as I stick it in a procedure, the parameters get changed to zero.

My procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDateRange
@DateMin varchar = NULL,
@DateMax varchar = NULL
AS
PRINT @DateMin;
PRINT @DateMax;
IF @DateMin IS NOT NULL AND @DateMax IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    PRINT @DateMin;
    IF(ISDATE(@DateMin)=1 AND ISDATE(@DateMax)=1)
        PRINT 'Valid Date';
    ELSE
        RAISERROR('Parameters not date format', 10, 1);
    END
ELSE
    RAISERROR ('Invalid parameters', 10, 1);
```

And my execute statement is:

```
EXECUTE spDateRange @DateMin='01/11/2011', @DateMax='01/12/2011';
```

And my output is:

```
0
0
0
Parameters not date format
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to give an explicit length for the `varchar` parameters. It defaults to 1 character.

`char(10)` should be enough for valid dates in `dd/mm/yyyy` format but I guess you might want longer as this is validating potentially invalid dates!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDateRange
@DateMin varchar(30) = NULL,
@DateMax varchar(30) = NULL
AS
```

Comment: Oh wow. Such a small mistake, I should have caught that. Thanks a ton