# Scalar Valued Function not return anything

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Stored Procedure Parameters being Corrupted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380350/sql-stored-procedure-parameters-being-corrupted)

I am stuck in a situation where a simple SQL Server Scalar Valued function is returning 0. 
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[OpeningBalance]
(
    @AccountCode AS varchar,
    @FromDate AS datetime
)
RETURNS numeric
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Balance AS numeric

    SELECT     
      @Balance = SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit)
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT     
            CASE 
               WHEN Debit - Credit > 0 THEN Debit - Credit 
               ELSE 0 
            END AS Debit, 
            CASE 
              WHEN Credit - Debit > 0 THEN Credit - Debit 
              ELSE 0 
            END AS Credit
        FROM
        (
             SELECT     
               SUM(VoucherDetail.Debit) AS Debit, 
               SUM(VoucherDetail.Credit) AS Credit
             FROM          VoucherMaster AS VoucherMaster 
             INNER JOIN VoucherDetail AS VoucherDetail 
                     ON VoucherMaster.ID = VoucherDetail.VoucherMasterID
             WHERE (VoucherDetail.AccountCode = @AccountCode) 
               AND (VoucherMaster.VoucherDate < @FromDate)
        ) AS Data
        UNION ALL
        SELECT     
          CASE 
            WHEN OpeningBalance > 0 THEN OpeningBalance 
            ELSE 0 
          END AS Debit, 
          CASE 
            WHEN OpeningBalance < 0 THEN OpeningBalance * - 1 
            ELSE 0 
          END AS Credit
        FROM ChartofAccounts
        WHERE (AccountCode = @AccountCode)
    ) AS OpeningData
    RETURN @Balance
END
```

However if I run this query in query analyzer it gives me required answer.

Comment: `query analyzer` ? Are you using `SQL Server 2000` or below?

Comment: I am using sql 2005. Query Analyzer means query editor.

Comment: Can you please post the `SELECT` command that is giving you 0. I don't see any thing wrong will your `Function` definition.

Comment: Thanks for all of you, I am able to figure out the problem. It is @AccountCode length, when I define it as varchar(8), all works fine. Thanks everyone for giving me your precious time.